# Experience vs Framework: PHP vs Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a new web project, and I can choose my tool of choice, and I've taken it down to two platform choices: PHP and Rails.

Now, I am not a startup, I am a professional programmer working for a large company, and they expect me to keep to deadlines, as well as be able to maintain the application, which includes scaling it when necessary, and be able to do performance tuning as needed.

My initial tool of choice is PHP, as I have 5 years working in it. I think know its ins and outs, and I am quite predictable with it (I know how long a project will take).

I can also do it in Rails. My experience is zero, but it is okay to include the time required to learn it in the project schedule.

Once again, I am a professional programmer, and I can code in C, C++, C#, Basic, Assembly, Java, Python, Lisp, SQL, PHP, and some others, so learning a new language is most likely not a difficult thing for me.

Hardcore ruby fans seem to love ruby and rails, and they claim that it is so extremely easy and elegant that by the next ruby version, the application will write itself just by thinking of it (exaggeration, hopefully). And it would be a nice thing to try it.

But I am mostly worried that even though learning the language is probably simple, learning how to do things correctly is something that takes experience.

Do you think all the benefits ruby and rails is claimed to have are so great that they overwhelm 5 years of experience in PHP?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no. But I'm a PHP guy, so I might be biased ;).

Ruby is great but PHP with a good framework (I'm a fan of Zend) has most of the same advantages. The big thing, as you say, is that experience means you know the *right* way to do things. It means you know how to avoid slowdowns, it'll be easier for you to debug, you'll feel more comfortable. Set up systems to avoid most of the things people complain about with PHP (in particular ensure you have good coding standards, good documentation and unit testing). If you can, develop to PHP 5.3+ and use namespaces.

I also think there's an advantage for your company in that there are more PHP people than Ruby people. This might just be my experience in a backwater Australian town but the glut of PHP people means you can always find a good one (for the right price). Rails people are harder to come by and although the quality of the worst people is higher for Ruby, it's harder to come by people at the top end. YMMV.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Common sense dictates the same thing you're saying. However, some ruby fans (and very high profile programmers at that) claim that ruby is an exception, that it has no gotchas, and the most trivial way of doing things is usually the right one. It's supposed to be so superlatively awesome that you will never want to code in anything else ever. I of course, am skeptic, and would like to know from pro rubyists whether 1 week of ruby can beat 5 years of php (On app dev speed and code maintenance. This is not an exaggeration, C# vs Asm is an example of this)

Comment: @mhr I had a project recently for a client who had a rails application developed for them which wasn't quite up to scratch. My job was to fix or replace it. I'm also a 5+ year PHP dev, with no rails. I tried to fix it in rails but just didn't feel comfortable enough to say I was doing my best work. (There were also a couple of fundamentally bad design decisions). I redid the whole thing in PHP (5.3 with ZF) and still think that was a good decision.

Comment: @mhr - No. One week of Ruby will not beat 5 years of PHP. Probably best to do your project in PHP. But definitely look into Rails for your side projects. Especially since you have experience with Lisp.

Comment: @mhr - I've worked with Ruby on Rails for about 2 years now and although I agree that it's a very easy language to learn and use, I'm still learning better ways of writing my code to improve performance and scaling. So yes you can do things quickly and easily in Rails, but like PHP, it takes time to learn all the ins and outs. As with @seph I'd recommend sticking to what you know for a new project - and have a play with Rails on the side.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using PHP for 3 years, and since I started Using Rails I never looked back to PHP.

Rails made my life easier, I have less code to maintain, a lot of plugins, and a very active community.

Answer (score 2):

Because of your 5 years of experience with PHP, I would say stick with that. You may not have trouble learning a new language, but you're most likely aware of the intricacies and 'gotchas' of PHP. Also, with PHP you can hit the ground running, versus getting up to speed with Rails.

If you do go with PHP, look at either Symfony or Zend Framework. Both are mature, robust frameworks that should handle most of the heavy lifting for you. I'm suggesting these two versus some of the other well-known frameworks (CakePHP, Code Igniter) because common consensus is that they're easier to extend which quickly becomes invaluable.

Remember that plans rarely work out exactly how you first envision them. You can reduce a lot of potential problems by sticking with a technology you already know.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend experimenting with Ruby first, because coding in other languages gives you a bit different perspective on things. 
If you have a serious project at hand though and never tried Ruby for smaller things - I would recommend against it. Designing an application requires a lot language specific decisions to be made and the larger the app the more important choices you will need to make upfront that will take time to adjust down the road.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the project under your control, and you are in the position to choose the tools, why not switch to a new language and new platform. As long as you do not expect to get the best results from the start. I would assume that doing your first Ruby on Rails website would take as long as you would in PHP. So actually, you are finished as fast as with PHP, and you learned something new in the process.

I believe that the Rails platform is indeed very nice, not to forget the Ruby language. But you will only be able to form your own opinion by playing with it. Either you make a small toy-application, or implement something real. I think you will be astounded (but I am biased, of course).

You should learn something new every year. That does not mean you have to keep using it. Maybe you only take the MVC part back to PHP applications, maybe nothing, or maybe you will fall in love with Ruby and Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen 15/20 years experts in C building linux kernel and modifying it in 1 minute. And also i have seen 30 years experts doing crestron/extron processor building. They prefer PHP, because its C flavour the native international programming C language.

Go for PHP, its open source, large community involved (respect it, so that you have problem, there will be a quick solution), experienced experts are involved, problem gets fixed rapidly, discuss about the problem, assign or make a report, its fixed done rapidly.

RedHat (Linux the largest contributor for famous Linux kernel) the famous SystemV mind genius/experts, is also behind it, they likes PHP (they find it as  "i smell C" oh yea).